# Mongoose docs clarification

Tags: mongoose

```
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
var parent = new Parent({ children: [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }] })
parent.children[0].name = 'Matthew';
parent.save(callback);
```

In the above code sample taken from the mongoose doc's site at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

```
parent.children[0].name = 'Matthew';
```

should be

```
parent.children[0].name = 'Matt';
```

if I am reading the docs correctly - I am new to mongoose, so I am seeking clarification.

Comment: No, it is correct as Matthew, as they are changing hte name from matt to matthew. or they are showing two different ways of storing fields in mongo document.

Comment: Please dont ask such questions on SO, these are not coding related questions. People are present here to help you solve your coding bgs and issues, not to clarify your documentation doubts. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to see what kind of questions you should ask here

Comment: Thank you Ravi. I was not aware that parent.children[0].name = 'Matthew'; over rides the previous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is correct as 'Matthew'

`parent.children[0].name = 'Matthew'` changes the name from 'Matt' to 'Matthew'.
Documentation is showing two different ways of storing field values in MongoDB Document.